# php echo javascript textbox hide not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, styles

i am trying to show or hide the textbox or form of html while clicking on link button which is generated via echo php statement..

but it does not work..

```
<script>
function onHide()
{
    alert("hide");
    document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "block";
    $("#txt").show();
} 
</script>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" style="display: none;">
    <input id="btn" value="hide/show" type="button" "value="hide/show" onclick="onHide()" /><!-- here onHide works -->

<?php
echo "<br/><a onclick='onHide()' id=".$row['id'].">Edit</a>";//this does not work..
?>


</body>
```

please anyone help me.. where is my mistake?

Comment: why did you repeat the value attribute?

Comment: You have a typo in your HTML - a repeated `value` attribute, and the second one has a mis-matched `"` before it. That aside, your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q3L834ua/ Please add some detail about your actual problem to the question.

Comment: thank u for your reply but my query is the onHide funtion doesn't work with echo <a> tag's onclick call..

Comment: Can you confirm that your actual code is as presented here?  Is your php code in a separate js file?  (just checking)

Comment: no.. php code and js all are on same file..

Answer (score 1):

Correct value `"`

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="hide/show" onclick="onHide()" />
```

And Use below script

```
<script>
function onHide()
{
    alert("hide");
    $("#txt").toggle();
} 
</script>
```

Also include `jQuery` if not included on the page

Comment: oh yes.. sorry my typing mistake.. but my problem is not that.. though it does not work..  my question is  jquery or javascript is not worked on runtime generated php html tag..

Comment: If this is the problem then place script in the footer then it will work
jQuery works on dynamically generated tags

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in syntax:

Your wrote:

```
type="button" "value="hide/show"
```

But need:

```
type="button" value="hide/show"
```